# Set cell to variable using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to set a certain cell in a database to a variable in `PDO`. The code I am using now is:

```
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$player = "ryr11";
//$player = $_GET["pname"];
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = :player");
    $stmt->execute(array("player" => $player));

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if ( count($result) ) { 
        foreach($result as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }   
    } else {
        echo "No rows returned.";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I want each column to have it's own variable, so I can echo the cell content. As of now, it is only showing it in an array.

Comment: http://in2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $row['cell_name'];
```

[fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)  returns an  associative array.

Comment: Where would I put that, because If I remove the `$result = $stmt->fetchAll();`, then `$result` is undefined.

Comment: inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I tried that, but the `if statement` before the `foreach loop` uses `$result`, so I get an undefined variable error when I do that,

Comment: I can't believe this answer got +3. The system Stack Overflow scoring it's posts need to be revised.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch())
  {
     echo 'username : '. $result["username"].'<br />';
     echo 'cell_name2 : '. $result["cell_name2"].'<br />';
     echo 'cell_name3 : '. $result["cell_name3"].'<br />';
     .....
     ...
     etc
  }
```

or you can use a html table style

Comment: Use $result instead . since you don't have any Variable named $row

Comment: Try to remove the "foreach($result as $row) {print_r($row);}" and replace it with the code i gave you. don't forget to put the right column name instead of cell_name .

Comment: That just echoes nothing. I also want to be able to use $cell_name in other places in the code.

Comment: Also it doesn't work if I set the search value to a certain value, not using $_GET